# Be sure that the Startup.cs for your application is calling AddSwaggerGen from within ConfigureServices in order to generate swagger file

Tags: swagger, azure-web-app-service, .net-6.0, azure-api-management

I'm getting the above error message when publishing my .NET 6 API project to Azure API Management Service.

On analysis, I understood the reason for the issue is, while configuring services (for DI) in 'Program.cs', we are trying to fetch an Environment variable, which returns null and an exception is thrown. Somehow, this prevents creating the swagger.json file.

Two things that I'm trying to understand are,

1. Fetching the environment variable using "Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()" is not fetching the value in 'Program.cs', but the same works in controller action method.
2. If I comment out everything related to swagger, this issue is not occurring.

In the Publish Window, under 'Service Dependencies', I have configured my APIM resource details to deploy/update the APIs in the APIM directly.

[image: APIM configuration in Publish window]

Below is a sample code screeshot which replicates the issue.

[image: Sample issue code]

Please share your thoughts.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you publish a .NET 6 API to [Azure API Management](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/api-management/#features)? _> `publishing my .NET 6 API project to Azure API Management Service.`

Comment: some code would be helpful , like at which place you are trying to read environment variable and how are you configuring swagger ?

Comment: Could you please share your `Program.cs` and `appsettings.json` file?

Comment: @MarkusMeyer Please find the details in the updated post.

Comment: @CodingMytra Please find the details in the updated post.

Comment: @Harshitha, I've pasted a sample Program.cs above, appsettings.json is default

Comment: @Amateur_coder - You are trying to get the EnvironmentVariable Key, where you have set that `KEY` ? You need to set that `KEY` either in `appsettings.json` or `Azure App Service` Configuration section

Comment: @Harshitha, Yea, The `KEY` is set in `Azure App Service` Configuration, when I'm publishing, it's supposed to take the value from there only, right? It's not happening

Comment: Working on it, will let you know.

Comment: Please refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-aspnet-core-app?tabs=core6x#read-from-the-app-configuration-store)

Comment: does it work locally ?if it works locally it means some issue with the way you are supplying environment variable in azure.

Comment: Try to configure it to generate swagger v2 instead of the default v3, there are some known issues with swagger v3 or to troubleshoot effectively, export v3 version locally and try to import it manually and see if it works or not.

Comment: @CodingMytra Yes, it works without any error (able to fetch the Environment variables) locally. In Azure App Service, I've configured the same values but it doesn't fetch the values, still no clue.

Comment: @Harshitha, Yes, I've set the values in Azure App Service Configuration.

Comment: @Amateur_coder, Your issue is nothing to do with swagger, I suggest you update it accordingly to avoid confusion and unnecessary discussions

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps to publish a web app. If you follow these steps then you will not get this error:

1. Go to Azure portal > Web App > Overview. Click on <kbd>Download publish profile</kbd> (Refer screenshot). This will download a *.PublishSettings file:

   [image]
2. Now go to Visual Studio. Right click on project file in solution explorer > Click on **Publish** in context menu. This will open Publish window.
3. Now click <kbd>New profile</kbd> under publish tab (Refer screenshot):

   [image]
4. Now follow the **Import Profile** option to import the downloaded profile (Refer screenshot):

   [image]
5. After the profile has got imported, click <kbd>Publish</kbd> to complete the publish process (Refer screenshot):

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Initially even I got the same error with the given code.

[image]

The issue is at getting the Environment Variable.

To get the Key Value(Environment Variable) from Azure App settings, use the below line of code.

```cs
var key1 = app.Configuration.GetValue<String>("KEY");
```

**My Azure App Setting:**
[image]

Change `app.UseSwaggerUI` to

```cs
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
    options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
});
```

***My Program.cs***

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
var app = builder.Build();

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(app.Configuration.GetValue<String>("KEY")))
    throw new Exception("Error");

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
    options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
});


app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

***My appsettings.json***

```cs
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "KEY": "Your Connection String"
}
```

Make sure you have installed the `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` latest package.

***.csproj file***

```cs
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
```

***Output:***

[image]

Comment: I believe your code is fetching the data from your appsettings.json file rather than the App Service Configuration. Please remove the configuration from the appsettings and try the same thing. Also, I'm unable to view your screenshots not sure why.

Comment: If we want to override the Environment variables/ values from `Azure App Settings`, the same key must exist in the local `appsettings.json` file as well.