# Can't load webapi from App Service in APi Management

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-web-api, azure-api-management

We are setting up an APi Management instance in Azure and we want it to integrate the definitions of a WebApi developed in .NET Core5 and published as an App Service.

The problem is that when we try to directly load the API as AppService, the method definitions are not loaded, and a generic method appears for each HTTP verb.

[image]

We have tried loading it as OPENApi Definition, and the definitions are loaded but it gives us the impression that it does not link with the real app service, since the calls that we make externally by postman to the appservice are not seen in the API Management monitoring

[image]

[image]

I don't know what we are doing wrong.

We have tried adding the following to startup.cs

```
var swaggerOptions = new SwaggerOptions();
        Configuration.GetSection(nameof(SwaggerOptions)).Bind(swaggerOptions);

        app.UseSwagger(option =>
       {
           option.RouteTemplate = swaggerOptions.JsonRoute;
           option.SerializeAsV2 = true; // this is optional to control the swagger version
       });


        app.UseSwaggerUI(option =>
        {
            option.SwaggerEndpoint(swaggerOptions.UIEndpoint, swaggerOptions.Description);
        });
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Please share your Controller HttpPost method code which you are trying to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Check the below steps to load the API's***

After deploying the app from Visual Studio,Navigate to the API Management in the Azure Portal.

All the operations will be available under the `Test` tab.

- Click on `API`=> `All API's` = >`Test` and select an operation which you want to execute.

[image]

[image]

***Output from AppService .NET Core 5:***

[image]

As .NET Core 5 is Out of Support, it may not work as expected.

[image]

Advice you to migrate to `.NET Core 6`.

Refer this [SOThread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74093408/19648279) to Work with .NET Core 6 API.